# Query excluding only 1 of many expected rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm performing a user search but want to exclude any users that have blocked the searcher.  This is what I have so far but **it keeps including all but one blocked users in results**. I've tried several combinations but am not sure how to get around it.  I've also considered splitting up the queries and using PHP to filter out the users that are in the blocks table.

The results should return iosuser1 only.

```
> +----------+---------+-----------+
|username  |zipcode  |birthdate  |
+----------+---------+-----------+
|tester55  |72758    |1999-09-09 |
+----------+---------+-----------+
|tester86  |60608    |1983-05-10 |
+----------+---------+-----------+
|iosuser1  |10011    |1975-12-19 |
+----------+---------+-----------+
|iosuser5  |10011    |1975-12-21 |
+----------+---------+-----------+


Blocks table
+----------+---------+-----------+
|blocker   |blockeduser
+----------+---------+-----------+
|tester86  |tester55 |          |
+----------+---------+-----------+
|iosuser5  |tester55 |         |
+----------+---------+-----------+

Zip Code table
+----------+---------+-----------+
|zipcode   |city
+----------+---------+-----------+
|72758     |Rogers   |          |
+----------+---------+-----------+
|60608     |Chicago  |         |
+----------+---------+-----------+
SELECT
zipcodes.zip,
zipcodes.city,
zipcodes.state,
users.*,
YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(users.birthdate) -(
    RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) < RIGHT(users.birthdate, 5)
) AS age, blocks.blockeduser, blocks.blocker,
center.seekingdistance,
(
    3959 * ACOS(
        COS(RADIANS(zipcodes.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(center.latitude)) * COS(
            RADIANS(zipcodes.longitude) - RADIANS(center.longitude)
        ) + SIN(RADIANS(zipcodes.latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(center.latitude))
    )
) AS distance
FROM
    (
        (
        SELECT
            users.username,
            users.zip,
            users.seekingdistance,
            users.seekingGender AS wantgender,
            users.seekingrace AS wantrace,
            users.seekingmarital AS wantmarital,
            users.seekingminage AS wantminage,
            users.seekingmaxage AS wantmaxage,
            users.seekingminheight AS wantminheight,
            users.seekingmaxheight AS wantmaxheight,
            users.seekingbodytype AS wantbodytype,
            users.seekingreligion AS wantreligion,
            users.seekingeducation AS wanteducation,
            users.seekingoccupation AS wantoccupation,
            users.seekingpolitics AS wantpolitics,
            users.seekingkids AS havekids,
            users.seekingwantkids AS wantwantkids,
            users.seekingdrink AS wantdrinker,
            users.seekingsmoke AS wantsmoker,
            users.gender AS mygender,
            zipcodes.latitude,
            zipcodes.longitude
        FROM
            (
                users
            JOIN zipcodes ON users.zip = zipcodes.zip
            )
        WHERE
            (username = 'tester55')
    ) center,
    zipcodes, blocks
    )
INNER JOIN users ON zipcodes.zip = users.zip
WHERE
    (
        users.username <> 'tester55' AND users.birthdate >= DATE_SUB(
            NOW(), INTERVAL wantmaxage YEAR) AND users.birthdate <= DATE_SUB(
                NOW(), INTERVAL wantminage YEAR) 
            ) AND NOT IN (SELECT blocks.blocker from blocks INNER JOIN users on users.username = blocks.blocker WHERE blocks.blockeduser = "tester55" and blocks.blocker = "tester86")
        HAVING
            (
                distance < center.seekingdistance
            ) 
        ORDER BY
            distance
```

Comment: update your question and add  also the expected  result related  to your data sample

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge I've updated the question with the expected results.

Comment: @scaisEdge found an error in results so updated with correct expected and more info on the problem.

Comment: your query is too complex  respected the question for exclude  .. rows .. is not clear how and why the exclusion should work .. you should build a more simple case ..

Comment: It's search query that searches by preferences and distance.